# Submit Form With Unique HREF

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I want to make it so I have a delete page option in the form of an href link. Problem is I can't figure out how to send data ( POST or GET ) to the server to make it work.
My idea is something along the lines of

```
<li><a href="javascript:void()" id="page" name="page" value="'.$row['id'].'" onClick="DeletePage()">Delete Page</a></li>

<script>
function DeletePage() {
            $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'calls.php',
            data: $("#deletepage").serialize() + $("#page").val(),
            success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            }
          });
}
</script>
```

I have the process set in the deletepage form. IE. A hidden variable named process that tells the calls page to run a deletepage function.
Is there any way to do this?
I've made some changes to my form structure and I have

```
foreach($resource as $row){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['enabled']."</td>";
                echo '<td><div class="input-group-btn">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span></button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="./editpage.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Edit Page</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Disable Page</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Enable Page</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <form id="deletepage">
                        <input type="hidden" name="process" id="process" value="deletepage">
                        <input type="hidden" name="pageid" id="pageid" value="'.$row['id'].'">
                        </form>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void()" id="page" name="page">Delete Page</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div></td>';
                echo "</tr>";
```

Now it works (Kind of) I can delete the first page, but after that it doesn't take the data past that and generate a new form. I'm thinking it's because the form id just pulls from the first form with that name so I would have to give the form a unique name and then create the ajax function within the loop as well.
Calls.php

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/settings.php');
if(isset($_POST['process'])){
    switch($_POST['process']){
        case 'login':
        $static->Login();
        break;
        case 'logout':
        session_destroy();
        break;
        case 'updatepage':
        $admin->UpdatePage();
        break;
        case 'addpage':
        $admin->AddPage();
        break;
        case 'deletepage':
        print_r($_POST);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are now sending the form... why not sending there the data?? or in the url?   `url:'calls.php?yourvar=xxxx' `

Comment: Sure, if you just have one id for multple forms, it´ll just run the first one located i think

Comment: I think you're right, so I think what I'll have to do is generate each form with a unique id attached. Then also generate the ajax script.

Comment: I' ve edited my answer. Check it. Maybe it´s what u need. Check i did change the $("#deletePageForm") to $(".deletePageForm") to look for all the different forms (you must add this class to the form)

Comment: I had actually tried that before and what ended up happening was it returned the value of the last form instead of the first. Thank you for the brainstorming.

Comment: ok!! nice anyway!! thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are using Jquery.  It has a better (easier) post() method:  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

There you have that example to call php functions:

```
$.post( "test.php", { func: "getNameAndTime" }, function( data ) {
  console.log( data.name ); // John
  console.log( data.time ); // 2pm
}, "json");
```

**EDIT**

I suppose that is what you want to approximate (with all together):

```
 $.post( "test.php", { func: $("#page").val(), mydata: $("#deletepage").serialize() }, function( data ) {
      console.log( data.name ); // John
      console.log( data.time ); // 2pm
    }, "json");
```

**EDIT 2**  After talking about some forms with the same id, maybe that may help you:

```
function DeletePage() {

 $("body").find(".deletePageForm").each(function(index, element){
        $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'calls.php',
        data: $(element).serialize() + $("#page").val(),
        success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        }
      });

   });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this seems quite generic. I understand how ajax and jquery works for the most part. My intent is actually to take an href link and utilize it as a post within the query. The calls page would then run the function to delete the unique id attached to the href to delete a page from the database. I appreciate the input though!

Comment: but i don´t understand... you are now in the calls page, and you now have A hidden variable named XX that tells the calls page to run a deletepage function.... what do you want then? i think i´m missing something!

Comment: It will never redirect to the calls page. The calls page is a switch page that is called in the background of ajax and then send notifications to the page. I'll post an example of the calls page and maybe that will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery.ajax or URL:

```
<li><a class="edit_page"><input type="hidden" value="' . $row['id'] . '">Delete Page</a></li>

    <script>
    $(".edit_page").click(function(){
        var page_id = $(this).find('input').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'calls.php',
            data: {id : page_id},
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

URL

```
<?php echo '<li><a href="calls.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a></li>';?>
```

or something like this

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
  echo '<li><a href="calls.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a></li>'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The final result is to give a unique identifier to the forms and generate the ajax script within the foreach loop.
What Ended up passing the data needed is:

```
        foreach($resource as $row){
            echo '    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>';
                echo "<script>
                $(function () {
                $('#page".$row['id']."').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'calls.php',
            data: $('#deletepage".$row['id']."').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
              alert(data);
            }
          });

        });

      });
</script>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['enabled']."</td>";
                echo '<td><div class="input-group-btn">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span></button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="./editpage.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Edit Page</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Disable Page</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Enable Page</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <form id="deletepage'.$row['id'].'">
                        <input type="hidden" name="process" id="process" value="deletepage">
                        <input type="hidden" name="pageid" id="pageid" value="'.$row['id'].'">
                        </form>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void()" id="page'.$row['id'].'" name="page'.$row['id'].'">Delete Page</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div></td>';
                echo "</tr>";
```

I appreciate any help that was given that pointed me in different ways.

Comment: did u tried doing it without id´s ? just with classes? it sure will be helpful